# Using jQuery to add elements without displacing other elements

Tags: javascript, jquery, html

I have a list on my website and I would like to add a mouseenter function so that two lines appear when the mouse moves over one item and disappear when the mouse leaves. I am able to make the lines appear and disappear, but when they do they move the list items up and down, which reduces functionality and is aesthetically unappealing. I would like to make the lines appear (one above and one below the SPAN) without displacing the elements in the list.

Here is my code and a demonstration: http://jsfiddle.net/strw22fe/

script:

```
     $(document).ready(function(){
              $("SPAN").mouseenter(function() {
                                   var line = "<hr>";


                                    $("SPAN").eq(this.id-1).before(line);
                                 $("SPAN").eq(this.id-1).after(line);
                                 });
              });
$(document).ready(function(){
              $("SPAN").mouseleave(function() {

                                   $("hr").remove();
                                   });
              });
```

Note: I have applied this function to the span because I can control its width more easily than I can the width of an li.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Best way is to do it using CSS `:hover`

Something like this should do fine.

Remove your JS code and insted use the following CSS code

```
li:hover{
    border-top: 1px solid black;
    border-bottom: 1px solid black;
}

li{
    list-style-position: inside;
    border-top: 1px solid transparent;
    border-bottom:1px solid transparent;
}
```

Here is your [updated fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/strw22fe/3/).

Comment: I would suggest adding a transparent border (1px top and bottom) to the li element to prevent the visual issue Jonathan was wanting to avoid.

Answer (score 2):

I agree with Maverick, but I would expand the css so the elements don't move around and the border goes above and below the bullet point:

```
li:hover{
    border-top: 1px solid black;
    border-bottom: 1px solid black;
}

li{
    list-style-position: inside;
    border-top: 1px solid transparent;
    border-bottom:1px solid transparent;
}
```

Comment: This answer is more relevant. I was thinking of doing it using box shadow but using borders only makes more sense. Thank you. :)

Answer (score 1):

Sure enough, you should go with CSS, as suggested by Maverick.
Interesting solution the transparent borders, even if in your *(simple)* case I'd rather do something like this:

```
    li{
        list-style-position: inside;
    }
    li:hover {
        border-top:1px solid;
        border-bottom:1px solid;

        /* just subtract the 2px added by the border-top and border-bottom from the height of the <li> */
        margin:-1px 0 -1px 0; 
    }
```

re-(re-re-)updated fiddle [here](http://jsfiddle.net/strw22fe/4/). ;)

Answer (score 0):

There are a couple of ways to keep the span elements in place when the extra lines are added:

1. Initialize the page with space for the lines, so that when you add the lines you don't need extra space and don't have to move the elements.
2. If you are adding something like a tooltip, which isn't the case, you can make the element float above the rest of the elements so elements don't get re-sized.